# Почему я не могу передать переменную в функцию?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Если я вместо переменной напишу число, все норм работает. Если пытаюсь передать через переменную то же число, не работает, ошибок не показывает. `console.log(max)` выводит число `5000`

```
function getChart(div_id, div_current, div_max){


      var max = div_max;
      var current = div_current;

      var chartRpm = Highcharts.chart(div_id, Highcharts.merge(gaugeOptions, {
        yAxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: max,
            title: {
                text: 'RPM'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'RPM',
            data: [current],
            dataLabels: {
                format: '<div style="text-align:center"><span style="font-size:20px;color:' +
                    ((Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black') + '">{y:f}</span><br/>' +
                       '</div>'
            },
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' revolutions/min'
            }
        }]

      }));
```

Comment: возможно у вас строковая переменная? `+max` попробуйте.

Comment: А что означает запись \*\*max\*\*?

Comment: пытался выделить переменную, только сейчас увидел

Comment: @teran а почему так происходит? я число добавлял в переменную, а на выходе текст?

Comment: @max что бы ответить, нам надо увидеть, как вы добавляли число в переменную.

Comment: @max может вы его откуда нить с Json тащите, сгенерированный на пхп. но вопрос не в этом, конвертация в число помогает, или нет?

Comment: Спасибо, это решило проблему, число беру из `data-attr`

Comment: @max оформил ответом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highcharts - не особо всеяден к формату передаваемых данных, так что если вы передали строку, там где ожидается число (даже если эта строка является эквивалентом числа), то скорее всего график просто не будет нарисован.

Чаще всего такая ситуация бывает, когда данные для графика выбраны из БД, закодированы в json, и переданы в highcharts, при этом если явно на каком-то этапе не указывать, что значения - числовые, то на выходе будут получены строки.

В вашем же случае `data()` метод, возвращает строку. Которую нужно явно, или неявно привести к числу, перед передачей в highcharts, и унарный плюс вполне решает данную задачу: `+max`

Так что, если вы строите график, все вроде корректно, ошибок в консоли нет, а график так и не рисуется, то проверьте формат передаваемых данных.